# Linux shell get value of a field from a yml file

Tags: yaml

I have a database.yml file like

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: d360
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: password

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: sample
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: password
```

Now, I want value of database of test environment (that is `sample` for the YAML shown).
How can we do that using sed?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That is fairly easy, not using `sed`, but with appropriate shell tools. First, if you need to preserve `sample` in a variable for later use, then something like the following will work using bash **substring replacement** to isolate `sample` on the **Test:/database:** line:

```
$ db=$(grep -A3 'test:' database.yml | tail -n1); db=${db//*database: /}; echo "$db"
sample
```

or for a shorter solution that you can dump to the command line, remove the variable and command substitution and use a tool like `cut`:

```
$ grep -A3 'test:' database.yml | tail -n1 | cut -c 13-
sample
```

or, with `awk`, simply:

```
$ grep -A3 'test:' database.yml | tail -n1 | awk '{ print $2}'
sample
```

All of the different ways can be used inside **command substitution** (i.e. `var=$(stuff)` ) to store `sample` in `var`, it is just a matter of which you would rather use. I think you get the idea.

Comment: I've seen this before `db=${db//*database: /}`, but what/how do we call this?

Comment: @bretonics - that is a *parameter expansion with substring replacement*. It takes the existing variable `db` in `=${db` then will replace *every* occurrence `//` of `*database: ` with `/...` (nothing). (note the closing `'/'` is implied). So you are simply removing every occurrence of `*database: ` from `db` and assigning the modified result back to `db`.

Comment: This type of code assumes you know the format of the input file... if that's the case why not `grep -m2 database | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'`?

Answer (score 30):

There are better tools than `sed`. You might be stuck on a minimal system, but other people looking for an answer probably won't be.

The python version of [yq](https://pypi.org/project/yq/) acts like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ pip3 install yq
$ yq -r .test.database database.yml
sample
```

[shyaml](https://github.com/0k/shyaml) works too, but has an odd restriction that you can only redirect into it:

```
$ pip3 install shyaml
$ shyaml get-value test.database < database.yml
sample
```

If `perl` is around and you have YAML installed:

```
$ cpan YAML
$ perl -MYAML -le 'print YAML::LoadFile(shift)->{test}{database}' database.yml
sample
```

Or, if you want `ruby`:

```
$ ruby -r yaml -e 'puts YAML.load_file(ARGV[0])["test"]["database"]' database.yml
sample
```

Answer (score 14):

On Ubuntu, install `yq`:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install snapd
$ sudo snap install yq
```

Use `yq`:

```
$ value=$(yq r database.yml test.database)`
```

Comment: There is a difference in usage between the snap and the Python package.
  
snap version(4.6.0):
`yq .test.database database.yml -j`
python version(2.12.0):
`yq eval .test.database database.yml`

Answer (score 8):

YAML obviously isn't natively supported in shell.  But sed also isn't a YAML parser.  Neither are grep, tail, cut, etc.  I'm pretty sure you'd need an actual *language* in which to write a proper parser.  Awk, perl, python, erlang, etc.

You could use sed or shell or somesuch if you know that your YAML data will always be formatted in a certain way or hold certain values in a particular order, but to make a parser that will work *generally*, and on any ol' YAML file you point it at, you'll need to emulate the parsers that already exist in other languages.

If you don't want to write your own (perhaps asking the StackOverflow community for help once you have some code to consider), then one option might be to install a tool like [shyaml](https://github.com/0k/shyaml) which can accurately parse files and give you authoritative content.  A quick solution easily implemented into your scripts, though it has some dependencies (python).

Comment: This is a better answer that will lead to better solutions (in that they will break less when the yaml file changes... and believe me the yaml file will change).

Answer (score 3):

For macOS / Linux users using Homebrew, `yq` is available, and provides a `jq`-like expeience:

```
$ brew install yq
$ yq eval .test.database database.yml
sample
```